# Advantages of Auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0

We have a web platform with 5 sites. Authentication is implemented with login/password only. My management told me that we need to add social login with Google and Facebook and for it I should look to [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) solution.

I checked it, it's look quite interesting but could somebody give me the real benefits of it's integration to our system what is quite difficult today? Price for 10 000 active users is 1440$ per month and I'm asking myself if it is really so difficult to implement social login?

In past, I created myself a simple prototype that logins with Google, it did not take a lot of time.

I suppose that everything is not so simple, so what am I missing and why do we have to buy this solution instead creating something simple ourselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question when I was researching about using Auth0. 
I came to these conclusions, but your mileage may vary.

Here are some of the pros of using Auth0:

- Almost any webapp you use is going to implement authentication. This is table stakes and there are lot of cookiecutter solutions for various frameworks, but can be hard to get it right and secured. One less thing to maintain and worry about when you are building your product. Their starter free plan is sufficient for most startups' needs.
- Auth0 has got SDKs in various languages and a ton of documentation. Its easy to integrate it with your application.
- It provides compliance with various standards(Ex: HIPAA), if that's a key requirement for your product.

Auth0 is not without its disadvantages. Remember that you are offloading your entire user data to a 3rd party app in exchange for flexibility. They do offer a way to [migrate this data back](https://auth0.com/docs/tutorials/removing-auth0-exporting-data) to your app in case you need it, thus avoiding any vendor lockin.